# АТ команды по UART STM32

Tags: c, arduino, stm32, микроконтроллеры

Переезжаю c ардуины на stm32, возникла проблема с UART'om а точнее с пониманием, как это сделать "красиво". Если в ардуине есть `String` и методы `read() / readString()`, то для stm нужно писать все ручками, подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм общения (возможно ссылки на статьи ) по uart посредством АТ комманд, ведь изначально я не знаю какой размер ответа и какого размера буфер создавать. Плюс еще три варината общения по UART, какой из них лучше подходит, для эмуляции ардуиновского `Serial.read()`

Comment: У них (STMicro) же была какая-то мощная библиотека, `HAL` по-моему называется или как-то так. Там всё уже выписано.

Answer (score 0):

Ну во первых, если используешь BluePill или BlackPill, то там есть ещё и уже распаянный USB разьём, и можно вместо использования USB-TTL переходников подключаться по USB , настроив виртуальный COM порт. Т.е. есть несколько вариантов, если хочешь подключить STM к ПК. Для подключения через виртуальный COM порт по USB мне помогло это видео https://youtu.be/4iSRUcb9GWM

У него так же есть и видео, как настроить UART
https://youtu.be/Yi5d2MQnQug
И у него ещё много видео про программирование STM32. На основе кода из видео про UART я сделал библиотеку, но она работает на C++ и с ней будут проблемы с изменением файлов,так что советую разобраться с видео материалом и возможно создать функции, аналогичные ардуиновским. Про  АТ комманды не совсем понятно, они в основном используются для WI-FI и Bluetooth модулей для настройки. На STM всё настраивается либо с помощью STML или cmsis, либо более лёгким способом через CubeMX и библиотеки HAL или LL.